# Android Studio cannot download components

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a strange issue with Android Studio SDK. I am trying to download some components and when download progress achieved is 100%, I get an error:

```
Preparing "Install Google Repository".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v8_rc42_wear_2a3.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v8_rc42_wear_2a3.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Google Repository" failed.
Preparing "Install Android Support Repository".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r40.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r40.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android Support Repository" failed.
Failed packages:
- Google Repository (extras;google;m2repository)
- Android Support Repository (extras;android;m2repository)
```

When I do it manually, links work.

Comment: I had encountered this problem just now. Just run the program as an administrator and it must fix your problem.

Comment: This solution here worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955241/android-studio-installation-bug/50662641#50662641

Answer (score 3):

It's look like you are trying to update Android Studio but you have a proxy which is not set in it.

If you wish to set one : Go to Preferences -> Appearence @ Behavior -> System settings -> HTTP Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Following Steps Worked for me.
Step 1: File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy
Step 2: Clear Password and Click Ok.