# Android Studio Installation BUG

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, installation

From yesterday i am having problems while installing android studio on my new SSD disc.

I tried to turn off firewall, windows defender, run android studio with ADMINISTRATOR rights, also i tried downloading JDK 8 , then JDK 10 ,
I have JAVA on my computer and when i try to run ANDROID STUDIO for the first time and when he try to download things like android sdk or similar i am getting always the same message like this;

> Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)". Downloading
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip':
>   Unsupported record version Unknown-192.23 , response: 200 OK
>   Warning:
>   An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools:
>   Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip':
>   Unsupported record version Unknown-192.23 , response: 200 OK. "Install
>   Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" failed.

I am always getting this for error when i try to start Android Studio Unsupported record version

> Unknown-192.23(<-- this numbers are always diffrent )

Thank you guys who will try to help me fix this

P.s. i am using Windows 7 64 bit & Vertex 60gb SSD

P.s. android studio all worked on older HARD DISC , is problem in hard?

This is FULL INSTALATION logs you can see a lot of mistakes and failer installations,why that happens ?

```html
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-192.23
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-192.23
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_r6_2_1.zip
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)" ready.
Installing Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)" complete.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 6.2.1)" finished.
Preparing "Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/3534162-studio.sdk-patcher.zip.bak
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" ready.
Installing SDK Patch Applier v4 in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" complete.
"Install SDK Patch Applier v4 (revision: 1)" finished.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 27.1.12)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4623001.zip
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 27.1.12)" ready.
Installing Android Emulator in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 27.1.12)" complete.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 27.1.12)" finished.
Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Tag mismatch!
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Tag mismatch!
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r27.0.1-windows.zip
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 27.0.1)" finished.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r27.0.3-windows.zip
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" finished.
Preparing "Install Google Repository (revision: 58)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip
"Install Google Repository (revision: 58)" ready.
Installing Google Repository in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository
"Install Google Repository (revision: 58)" complete.
"Install Google Repository (revision: 58)" finished.
Preparing "Install Sources for Android 27 (revision: 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-130.125
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 27: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-130.125
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Sources for Android 27 (revision: 1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-27_r01.zip
"Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 1)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 27 in C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27
"Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 1)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 1)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\NaTu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\package.xml
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-192.23
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-192.23
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Tag mismatch!
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Tag mismatch!
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-130.125
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 27: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip': Unsupported record version Unknown-130.125
, response: 200 OK.

Preparing "Install Android Support Repository (revision: 47.0.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip
```

Comment: try to copy one URL.  past it in your browser to download manually.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, changing access rights to your sdk solves the problems: `chmod -R 777 /usr/lib/android-sdk`. Android sdk location may vary and also you might wanna use a different access rights than 777.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same issue as i tried to install Android API 27. Each time i use the SDK manager it downloads but fails to install. Here is how i fixed it

1. Run Android Studio as administrator
2. Open SDK Manager
3. Click on "edit" found close to  "Android SDK location"

[image]

3. It opens a window that show a list of "Android SDK Platform" you have downloaded but not installed.

[image]

4. In my case, it shows API 27-  62MB. I clicked on this to install. After it successfully install my app works fine.

I hope this fix works for you

Comment: I have had this problem multiple times.. and every single time, I come to Stackoverflow to check for the fix. Lol. (+1 for clarity).

Answer (score 1):

Running Android Studio as Administrator will lead you to the solution mainly.I've also had similar issues in the past

Comment: Please use the comment section for this kind of answers

Answer (score 0):

**Method**-->1 The solution for this is:
Run Android Studio as Administrator.
Re run the update.
It will work.

**Method**-->2 And I notice some setting about Force https//... to be fetched using http://...
After using it, my download run normally:

**Method**-->3 Download zip file from this location
Extract it and move the emulator folder image for emulator folder into the SDK folder image for SDK folder
I hope it works for you as well, I was using Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

**Method**-->4 I experienced the same issue as i tried to install Android API 27. Each time i use the SDK manager it downloads but fails to install. Here is how i fixed it
Run Android Studio as administrator
Open SDK Manager
Click on "edit" found close to "Android SDK location"
It opens a window that show a list of "Android SDK Platform" you have downloaded but not installed.
it shows API 27- 62MB. I clicked on this to install. After it successfully install my app works fine.I hope this fix works for you

**Method**-->5 In my case,I checked windows update where some drivers were pending and some were incomplete.
Then I restarted by updating windows with proper network then android studio installed properly and SDK works.