# Android Studio SDK Cannot Be Downloaded

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development and I need help with the installation process with the following error code. I have tried a clean installation of Android Studio many times but the error pops up every time.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Please, post errors as text.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Here is the solution, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49955241/2196176).

Comment: @Sunny did you notice that the error in the link you posted is totally different?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a temporary solution, skip components downloading when open Android Studio

1. install android studio.
2. do not start studio after installation completed.
3. go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
4. you will find  idea.properties file
5. write this line at the end of the file disable.android.first.run=true
6. run android studio
7. After open android studio you can install needed components from SDK Manager

There are some more solutions on [this link](https://www.quora.com/While-Installing-Android-stucked-at-downloading-components-What-can-I-do-now) which you can try.