# Android Studio does not install the SDK due to an error, how could I solve this problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 10747824. Expected 345298795 bytes

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Connection closed at byte 10747824. Expected 345298795 bytes.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955241/android-studio-installation-bug/50662641#50662641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It show a dialog box, click "retry" button and install is done ^^

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After closing the installation screen, simply retry to do the installation and it will continue from where it left off.